# Add/Replace object from array of objects JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to Add/Replace the `object` from `array of objects` by testing some `properties` against `array object`

- Replace `object if name and id matches`
- Add `object` to the `array if name and id does not match from array objects`

I am using below code, its working fine but I am not sure is it a good solution.

```js
let arr = [{name: 'test1', id:1, data: {a:1} }, {name:'test2', id:2, data: {a:2}}]
let obj = {name:'test3', id:3, data: {a:3}}
let itemFound = false;
let newArr = arr.map((item)=>{
  let test = item.name === obj.name && item.id === obj.id;
  if(test){
 itemFound = true;
  }
  return test ? obj : item;
});

if(!itemFound){
 newArr.push(obj);
}
console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: If it works, perhaps Codereview is a better match?

Comment: You can use Array prototype with a custom method. @Dipak

Comment: Since it works, why not just `wrap` it in a `function`?

Comment: What can be the reason for down-vote. Instead it would be greater help if suggest edit.

Answer (score 17):

You could look for the index and update the array, if found or push the object.

```js
var array = [{ name: 'test1', id: 1, data: { a: 1 } }, { name: 'test2', id: 2, data: { a: 2 } }],
    object = { name: 'test3', id: 3, data: { a: 3 } },
    index = array.findIndex(({ name, id }) => name === object.name && id === object.id);

if (index === -1) {
    array.push(object);
} else {
    array[index] = object;
}

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wraping @Nina Scholz 's answer in a function

---

```
objectReplacer(arrayOfObjects, newObject) {

      let index = arrayOfObjects.findIndex((value) => value === newObject.value);

      if (index === -1) {
        arrayOfObjects.push(newObject);
      } else {
        arrayOfObjects[index] = newObject;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.find()`

```js
let arr = [{name: 'test1', id:1, data: {a:1} }, {name:'test2', id:2, data: {a:2}}]
let obj = {name:'test3', id:3, data: {a:3}}

const newArr = arr.slice();
const existingObj = newArr.find(item => item.name === obj.name && item.id === obj.id);

if(existingObj) {
    Object.assign(existingObj, obj);
} else {
    newArr.push(obj)
}

console.log(newArr)
```